# Material animation in android

Tags: android, android-animation

Can any one help me with animations in android I am learning the animation through android developer website but I am also looking for a good tutorial for that, What I am looking for is [something similar](https://material.io/guidelines/motion/material-motion.html#material-motion-how-does-material-move) any help will be appriciated

Comment: Please post your latest code and what you tried so far.

Comment: I didn't started yet, what I want is a lead to start from somewhere.

Comment: We don´t do recommendations here, sorry. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ask again if you got a specific question. Meanwhile you will find some recommendations (...) [at the tag site](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You  can use following library for  animation

- [Material-Animations](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations)

  > used for three main things:

  1. Animate activity layout content when transitioning from one activity to another.
  2. Animate shared elements (Hero views) in transitions between activities.
  3. Animate view changes within same activity
- [EasyAndroidAnimations](https://github.com/2359media/EasyAndroidAnimations)

  > Easy Android Animations is an animation library that aims to make android animations easier, with 50+ builtin animations, it allows you to introduce many complex animation effects in your application with one or two lines of code
- [Facebook pop animation](https://github.com/facebook/pop)

  > Pop is an extensible animation engine for iOS, tvOS, and OS X
- [Material](https://github.com/rey5137/material)

  > MaterialLibrary is an Open Source Android library that back-port Material Design components to pre-Lolipop Android.
- [AndroidViewAnimations](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations)

  > View shake animation.
- [View animator](https://github.com/florent37/ViewAnimator)

  > A fluent Android animation library,Animate multiple view from one method
- [AndroidViewAnimation](https://github.com/daimajia/AnimationEasingFunctions)

  > AndroidViewAnimation, which is an animation collection, to help you make animation easier.