# How to animate drawable image android

Tags: android, android-animation

I'd like to know how to animate a drawable image in android. That is I'm using [LuckyWheel](https://github.com/thanhniencung/LuckyWheel)
 library and in it there is a model class  `LuckyItem`

```
public class LuckyItem {
    public String text;
    public int icon;
    public int color;
}
```

This is the screen shot of the image

[image: Screen shot]

And this is the `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<LuckyItem> data = new ArrayList<>();
    Button btn,play;
    boolean flag=true;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        play=(Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent;
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        final LuckyWheelView luckyWheelView = (LuckyWheelView) findViewById(R.id.luckyWheel);

        LuckyItem luckyItem1 = new LuckyItem();
        luckyItem1.text = "100";
        luckyItem1.icon = R.drawable.test1;
        luckyItem1.color = 0xffFFF3E0;
        data.add(luckyItem1);

        LuckyItem luckyItem2 = new LuckyItem();
        luckyItem2.text = "200";
        luckyItem2.icon = R.drawable.test2;
        luckyItem2.color = 0xffFFE0B2;
        data.add(luckyItem2);

        LuckyItem luckyItem3 = new LuckyItem();
        luckyItem3.text = "300";
        luckyItem3.icon = R.drawable.test3;
        luckyItem3.color = 0xffFFCC80;
        data.add(luckyItem3);

        LuckyItem luckyItem4 = new LuckyItem();
        luckyItem4.text = "400";
        luckyItem4.icon = R.drawable.test4;
        luckyItem4.color = 0xffFFF3E0;
        data.add(luckyItem4);

        LuckyItem luckyItem5 = new LuckyItem();
        luckyItem5.text = "500";
        luckyItem5.icon = R.drawable.test5;
        luckyItem5.color = 0xffFFE0B2;
        data.add(luckyItem5);

        LuckyItem luckyItem6 = new LuckyItem();
        luckyItem6.text = "600";
        luckyItem6.icon = R.drawable.test6;
        luckyItem6.color = 0xffFFCC80;
        data.add(luckyItem6);
        //////////////////

        //////////////////////
        LuckyItem luckyItem7 = new LuckyItem();
        luckyItem7.text = "700";
        luckyItem7.icon = R.drawable.test7;
        luckyItem7.color = 0xffFFF3E0;
        data.add(luckyItem7);

        LuckyItem luckyItem8 = new LuckyItem();
        luckyItem8.text = "800";
        luckyItem8.icon = R.drawable.test8;
        luckyItem8.color = 0xffFFE0B2;
        data.add(luckyItem8);


        LuckyItem luckyItem9 = new LuckyItem();
        luckyItem9.text = "900";
        luckyItem9.icon = R.drawable.test9;
        luckyItem9.color = 0xffFFCC80;
        data.add(luckyItem9);

        luckyWheelView.setData(data);
        luckyWheelView.setRound(getRandomRound());

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(flag)
                {
                    play.setEnabled(false);
                    Log.d("ins", "called");
                }
                flag=false;
                int index = getRandomIndex();
                luckyWheelView.startLuckyWheelWithTargetIndex(index);
                int te=getRandomRound();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(te)+" rounds!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            });

        luckyWheelView.setLuckyRoundItemSelectedListener(new LuckyWheelView.LuckyRoundItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void LuckyRoundItemSelected(int index) {

                int icons = data.get(index - 1).icon;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(index), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                flag=true;play.setEnabled(true);

            }
        });
    }

    private int getRandomIndex() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        return rand.nextInt(data.size())+1;

    }

    private int getRandomRound() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        return rand.nextInt(5)+9;

    }
}
```

When wheel select any item I want to animate the icon of the sector. Image is a drawable file.

## Edit

I tried with [Tween Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Tween), but I could only animate the drawable(icon) from the center of the wheel. I want to animate the icon from its original position.

## Code

```
luckyWheelView.setLuckyRoundItemSelectedListener(index -> {

        if (!isAdded()) {
            return;
        }

        Bitmap icons = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), data.get(index - 1).icon);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.images);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(icons);
        scale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.scale);
        translate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.translate);
        final AnimationSet s = new AnimationSet(false);//false means don't share interpolators
        s.addAnimation(scale);
        s.addAnimation(translate);
        imageView.startAnimation(s);
        s.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
flag = true;
    });
```

translate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="7%p"
        android:toYDelta="-45%p" />
</set>
```

scale.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="0.5"
        android:toYScale="0.5">
    </scale>
</set>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/lucky_wheel_background"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/luckyWheel_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <rubikstudio.library.LuckyWheelView
            android:id="@+id/luckyWheel"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp333"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp333"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            app:lkwBackgroundColor="#FF9800"
            app:lkwCursor="@drawable/ic_spin_pointer"
            app:lkwTextColor="#263238">

        </rubikstudio.library.LuckyWheelView>

    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/images"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/play_btn"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp105"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp57"
        android:layout_below="@+id/luckyWheel_frame"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_spin_button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what kind of animation are you looking for??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44918817/material-animation-in-android/44919092#44919092

Comment: @sumit I want to zoom and make a transition of the image

Comment: that sounds too complex, as the sector is not a separate view (as I can see). You will have to edit the library sources to achieve it. But that is way to hard I think.

Comment: @VladMatvienko i dont want to animate sector. I want to animate the icon in the sector

Comment: sorry, but you've told that you do: `I want to animate the image of the sector`