# Text View Animation, In and Out

Tags: android, animation, textview, android-animation

Can Somebody point me in the right direction, I want to animate text views like in the image below, I want to emulate the same behavior with 30 view texts showing randomly.
I'm familiar with the translation animation, what I don't know how to do is the "step" for every movement, how to handle it. And the way they appear/disappear.
Just need a hint where to start.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44918817/material-animation-in-android/44919092#44919092

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[THIS](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html) is what I was looking for.
Code is in the sample, to modify.