# Facebook overlay animation

Tags: android, facebook, animation, overlay

Facebook is adding some new animation from last few updates. On selecting particular status text like (Xoxo , harry porter, celebration) , Some animations are appearing like below image:

[image]

You can check once we click on "Xoxo" word, Some hearts will appear for 1-2 second on screen with animation.
I can't figure what mechanism facebook is using to make this work.
Can anyone have any idea regarding this animation code ? Which component Facebook is using to show ? How can we integrate in our project? 
some hint or idea will make my day.

Comment: check this [Animation link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44918817/material-animation-in-android/44919092#44919092) it may help you

Comment: @Harsh did you get this done ? I am also looking for this type of animation

Comment: @Kathi Hey check my answer. you will get some idea.

Comment: Thank you but it's need more work on that lib to achieve my animations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After few days of research, I found some good code examples on Github which almost full fill above functionality. They are using Canvas for the animation.
Below are some links for reference:

1.https://github.com/DanielMartinus/Konfetti?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=5884

2.https://github.com/plattysoft/Leonids