# How to Create Such Transition Effect on Android Rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, transition, android-transitions, screen-rotation

I wanna to create this transition effect on View in Activity or Fragment like below in this Image... Please anyone give me some idea regarding this....
[image: Transition effect on Screen Rotation Android]

Comment: check this animation and link it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44918817/material-animation-in-android/44919092#44919092

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12153520/3660290) answer. You can't do such fancy animations on orientation change.